# What is the best place to setup apps initial version checks or load initial data from database

Tags: flutter, dart

What is the best place to set up apps initial version checks and update shared preferences or load initial data from the database in flutter apps?

Because I want to update some shared preferences on app load, even it's from the background.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use this logic:
To let the app startup be as fast as possible I do all checks in in first page after user log in.. usually that page is my main page.

So I do this

- splash
- check preferences and if there is a user I log it in
- after login sucvesfull I go to mainpage
- if there is no user in preferences I go to loginpage
- first method in login and main is where I check versions, do user login ecc

So you can let user open app super fast and only after app is rendered I do checks.. so user has the impression your app open app really fast.

Bye :)

Comment: Thanks Patrick, In my app users doesn't need to login to view main page content, only when they want to post a car listing or when they want to chat with sellers.. So what I will do is setup a Provider with a getter/Future then will load the app version where needed..